# multiprocessing.Pool to execute concurrent subprocesses to pipe data from mysqldump

Tags: mysql, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python to pipe data from one mysql database to another. Here is a lightly abstracted version of code which I have been using for several months, which has worked fairly well:

```
def copy_table(mytable):
    raw_mysqldump = "mysqldump -h source_host -u source_user --password='secret' --lock-tables=FALSE myschema mytable"
    raw_mysql = "mysql -h destination_host -u destination_user --password='secret' myschema"

    mysqldump = shlex.split(raw_mysqldump)
    mysql = shlex.split(raw_mysql)

    ps = subprocess.Popen(mysqldump, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess.check_output(mysql, stdin=ps.stdout)
    ps.stdout.close()
    retcode = ps.wait()
    if retcode == 0:
        return mytable, 1
    else:
        return mytable, 0
```

The size of the data has grown, and it currently takes about an hour to copy something like 30 tables. In order to speed things along, I would like to utilize multiprocessing. I am attempting to execute the following code on an Ubuntu server, which is an t2.micro (AWS EC2).

```
def copy_tables(tables):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        params = [(arg, table) for table in sorted(tables)]
        results = pool.starmap(copy_table, params)
    failed_tables = [table for table, success in results if success == 0]
    all_tables_processed = False if failed_tables else True
    return all_tables_processed
```

The problem is: almost all of the tables will copy, but there are always a couple of child processes left over that will not complete - they just hang, and I can see from monitoring the database that no data is being transferred. It feels like they have somehow disconnected from the parent process, or that data is not being returned properly.

This is my first question, and I've tried to be both specific and concise - thanks in advance for any help, and please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(mysqldump, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.check_output(mysql, stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.stdout.close()
retcode = ps.wait()
```

should be

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(mysqldump, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sps = subprocess.Popen(mysql, stdin=ps.stdout)
retcode = ps.wait()
ps.stdout.close()
sps.wait()
```

You should not close the pipe until the mysqldump process finished. And check_output is blocking, it will hang until stdin reach the end.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, with no observable change. I understand the purpose of stdout.close() to be - if the child process dies, make sure to return a SIGINT to the parent process.

Comment: @speedyturkey My mistake, check_output is blocking call, should be Popen too.

Comment: Early results look promising here. Fantastic answer, thank you!